# Is there a comprehensive guide to the Pickpocket's Promenade?

Tags: fallen-london

The Pickpocket's Promenade in the Spite is really useful for grinding certain items at lower (pre-POSI) levels. However, to get a substantial amount of Pickpocket's Trophies you need to be very efficient and figuring out all the possible trophies/progress/unseen combinations to devise a good strategy seems very time consuming.

Is there a comprehensive reference of the options available here with success and failure rewards?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't been able to find a really good reference for this. It seems that all the information is buried [very deeply in the Echo Bazaar wiki](http://fallenlondon.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Cards_-_The_Crowds_of_Spite), though. So I thought I'd collect all that information to provide such a reference.

### Collecting Trophies

The following is a table of all opportunity cards and their options. For each of them, I list `T/P/U`, where `T` is the amount of Pickpocket's Trophies you get or lose, `P` is the change in your Approaching your Destination quality and `U` is the change in your Unseen quality.

Note that for `T` and `U` positive numbers are good, and for `P` negative numbers are good. You don't want `U` to reach 0 or `P` to reach 10. Also `U` will never increase beyond 3. Some choices also include an annotation denoted by one of `†*²³"'` if there are other rewards than `T/P/U`.

```
                                                     Success     Failure
A Constable!
  Pass by hurriedly                                 +0/+2/+0
  Pick his pockets                                  +4/+1/+0    +0/+3/-2

A drunk
  Pass by                                           +0/+1/+0
  Easy prey                                         +1/+1/+0    +0/+1/-1

A mould-spangled curiosity shop
  Window-shopping                                   +0/-1/+1
  Take advantage of another window-shopper          +2/+1/+0    +0/+1/-1

A Shopkeeper
  Leave him                                         +0/+1/+0
  Lighten his load                                  +3/+1/+0    +0/+1/-1

A Special Constable
  Pass by hurriedly                                 +0/+1/+0
  Investigate his pockets                           +5/+1/+0    +0/+2/-2

A Street Performer
  Drift on                                          +0/+1/+1
  Lighten the pockets of the audience               +2/+1/+0    +0/+1/-1

A... pickpocket?
  Carry on                                          +0/+1/+0
  Swift his gropus!                                 +5/+1/+0    -3/+1/+0

An Argument
  Pass on by                                        +0/+1/+1
  Pick the pockets of the crowd                     +2/+1/+0    +0/+1/-1

Gaoler
  Avoid him                                         +0/+1/+0
  Steal from him                                    +2/+1/+0†   +0/+1/-1

Jack!
  Run!                                              +0/+3/+1
  Grab a little souvenir as he passes              +10/+2/+0    +0/+3/+0*
  Meet him head-on                                  +0/+0/+2²   +0/+0/-2³

The Actress
  Not too close                                     +0/+1/+0
  Close enough to snatch a jewel                    +3/+1/+0    +0/+1/-1

The Costermonger
  Avoid her watchful gaze                           +0/+1/+0
  Pick her pocket                                   +2/+1/+0    +0/+1/-5

The Rat-Catcher
  Slip past                                         +0/+1/+0
  Quietly does it                                   +0/+0/+0"   +0/+1/-1'

Watchful Eyes
  Speed your pace                                   +0/+2/+0    +0/+2/-1
  Slip past                                         +0/+1/+0    +0/+1/-1
____________________
†Nightmares +1CP
*Wounds +??
²Urchins +10CP, Criminals +10CP, Constables +10CP, Touching Lovestory +1
³Wounds +??
"Rats on a String +11, Venge-Rat Corpse +1
'Wounds +1CP
```

In summary, you don't really ever want to pick the first/free option, with the exception of *Window-shopping* for *A mould-spangled curiosity shop*. In the other cases, provided you're confident to succeed, the other option is always better. But also note, that there are some cards you don't really want to use at all, primarily *Watchful Eyes* because it only has negative effects, and some like *A drunk* which are very inefficient.

By far the best cards are *A Special Constable*, *A... pickpocket?* and *Jack!*

Remember that you can also use the non-card action *Loiter*, which will always give you `P` -1, but may also incur `U` -1 or -2, so this should be a sort of last resort, if none of your card options allow you to continue.

### Spending Trophies

And here is a list of what you can buy from the Pickpocket's Trophies:

- **Dispose of one Trophy:** 20 Deep Amber
- **Dispose of five Trophies:** 75 Silk Scraps, Shadowy +??
- **Dispose of ten Trophies:** 20 Whispered Secrets, 30 Jade Fragments, 30 Rostygold, 8-20x Moon-Pearls, 20-100 Glim, Shadowy +2CP
- **Dispose of twenty Trophies:** 6 Sapphires, 6 Venom-Rubies, 4 Flawed Diamonds, 3-8 Ostentatious Diamonds, Shadowy +5CP
- **Letters (thirty Trophies):** 1 Touching Love Story, 5 Compromising Documents, 2 Incendiary Gossip, Shadowy +??
- **Dispose of forty Trophies:** 2-3 Bombazine Scraps, 1-2 Whisper-Satin Scraps, Shadowy +??
- **Dispose of fifty Trophies via the Acquisitive Relicquarian:** 2 Presbyterate Passphrases, 10 Mysteries of the Elder Continent, Shadowy +??

Please let me know if a got anything wrong, or if you figure out how many change points you get in the places where it still says `+??`.